# How to block specific IP range in ufw?

Tags: 14.04, firewall, ufw

I open terminal and type

```
sudo ufw reject from 216.21.13.0/24 to any port 80
```

But when I pick a random IP such as 216.21.13.15 I noticed it is still pingable and reachable. Why does this happen?

Comment: try to check status sudo ufw status

Comment: Status is  active

Comment: Consider [using `prepend`](https://serverfault.com/a/1132998/407820)

Answer (score 12):

Tho things to consider:
I usually use deny, not reject.  I'm not sure if reject is valid, so it should be:

```
sudo ufw deny from 216.21.13.0/24 to any port 80
```

Also, if you have other rule for port 80, they may be running before this one.  Try looking at

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

And you should see an output like this:

```
[ 1] Anywhere                   DENY IN     x.x.x.x            
[ 2] Anywhere                   DENY IN     x.x.x.x               
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 22                         ALLOW IN    x.x.x.x              
[ 6] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)                      
[ 7] 443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

If your rule is after the allow all port 80 traffic, then it won't ever be called because the rule above it allows all port 80 traffic.

Try putting the rule in with

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 216.21.13.0/24 to any port 80
```

And it will put it at the top of the list.

Comment: What does the 0/24 do here?  Does the range go from 216.21.13.0 through 216.21.13.24?  I am trying to block an IP address that ends in 199.

Comment: The 0/24 is IP address slash notation.  In this case, you are specifying that 24 of the 32 bits for the IP address are defined.  That's a fancy way of saying that it covers the range 216.21.13.0-216.21.13.255.  You can specify a single IP address if that's what you're trying to do with the command sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 216.21.13.199 to any port 80.

More on IP address slash notation can be found here: https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing